# How I insert data into database with 20 second interval on page refreshing

Tags: php, mysql

I have a webpage where I getting live data through API in PHP. when I refresh the page, data updated on-page and also insert into MySQL database from APIs. But I want that I refreshing the page 100 times but data insert into a database with 20-sec interval. For exhale when I refresh the page at 10:00:00 am, the data insert into MySQL at 10:00:00 am. but then again I refresh the page at 10:00:10 am then data not insert into MySQL so on. I want that first data to insert at 10:00:00 am, second data at 10:00:20 am, third data 10:00:40 am and so on.

**My Code:**

```html
<?php
        $servername = "localhost";
        $username = "root";
        $password = "";
        $dbname = "trend";



        // Create connection
        $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

        // Check connection
        if ($conn->connect_error) {
          die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        }
        //echo "Connected successfully";

        $sql =  "INSERT INTO pload(GT1, GT2, ST, TL)
        VALUES($js_result1, $js_result2, $js_result3, $js_result_total)";

        if ($conn-> query($sql) === TRUE)
        {
            //echo "new record created ";
        }else{
            echo "Error"  .$sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
        }
        $conn->close();

    ?>
```

Comment: What's stopping you from achieving this? Edit question with details. Use paragraphs to make question readable.

Comment: sorry @danblack but I want a 20-second interval in timestamp and please to check my PHP code

Comment: That doesn't explain what difficulty you hare having. What is implementing the 20 second interval? Is the same code shown the same as the webpage script? Do you need it updated if noone is looking.

Comment: sir @danblack, actually my page refresh after 20 seconds but when I see in database data insert into with 2 or 3 seconds but I want my page in fact refresh 100 times in one minute but data insert into the 20-second interval. for example, when the page refresh at 12:00:00 then data insert at the as same time into the database next data come at 12:00:20 and next data is 12:00:40 and the next data is 12:01:00.

Answer (score 1):

Try reading the actual seconds and execute the insert query only when they are a multiple of 20:

```
$seconds=date('s');

if(($seconds % 20) == 0) {
   if ($conn-> query($sql) === TRUE)
   {
            //echo "new record created ";
   }else{
            echo "Error"  .$sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
   }
}
```